# Why my UI Grid cannot load the grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

[Here is my runnable plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oXEt5IfdrpkkPSxysncy?p=preview)

I followed the tutorial in [UI Grid official tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro).
I do not know why I cannot load the grid. I did not find any syntax error.

Here is part of errors from console:

> URL visited /
>   editor-1.2.0.js:2 URL visited /?p=catalogue
>   emmet.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   editor-1.2.0.js:7 AUTH Object
>   editor-1.2.0.js:2 Event tracked Plunk Beautify Toolbar undefined undefined
>   editor-1.2.0.js:2 Event tracked Plunk Save Toolbar undefined undefined
>   editor-1.2.0.js:2 URL visited /oXEt5IfdrpkkPSxysncy?p=catalogue
>   editor-1.2.0.js:2 Event tracked Multipane Show Preview Toolbar undefined undefined
>   editor-1.2.0.js:2 URL visited /oXEt5IfdrpkkPSxysncy?p=preview
>   run.plnkr.co/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/oXEt5IfdrpkkPSxysncy?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="myGrid"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid']);
        app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.myData = [{
                    "firstName": "Cox",
                    "lastName": "Carney",
                    "company": "Enoromo",
                    "employed": true
                }, {
                    "firstName": "Lorraine",
                    "lastName": "Wise",
                    "company": "Comveyer",
                    "employed": false
                }, {
                    "firstName": "Nancy",
                    "lastName": "Waters",
                    "company": "Fuelton",
                    "employed": false
                }
            ];
        }])
    </script>

    <style>
        .myGrid {
            width: 500 px;
            height: 250 px;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cdn for ui-grid was not correct. And all your src should point to a secure url i.e with *https*. The reason is you are trying to access an unsecure script from a secure site. This will be blocked since content can be served over only HTTPS.

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.6/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.6/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
  </head>
```

**Working Plunkr**:https://plnkr.co/edit/I87wgFzlqmtl6dcPem6F?p=preview

Comment: But, you can check this official plunker, they did not use https, etc
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue. Check again the official plunker, while you are adding popular paakages, it points to https rather than an insecure http server.

Comment: And If you are talking about script.js and style.css, that is beacuse its the same folder structure of plunkr , so they don't need to use https,  they can directly reference it.

Comment: But can you click "Edit in Plunkr" in this page "http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro". You can check in that plunkr, that did not use any https, but http. But they are working. I just want to know why they can work by using https, but my cannot work by working their script and style?

Comment: With http also it can work but the site has allow for it. But many sites doesn't allow insecure connection. So there we need to define https but this is not the major thing your url was incorrect

Comment: "But many sites like plunker doesn't allow insecure connection" But do you know why this works: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZMSXiHFhZNYYv4m2empO?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148731/discussion-between-vivz-and-codecontributor).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You provided me very detailed in the chat why my plunkr did not work. I did not know I need to connect to secure cdn if connect a secure site. Hope this link will help future developers who has the same problem as me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content